# Is this good code for asynchronous downloads on regular interval?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, timer, task-parallel-library

I am using a Windows Service to check for updates on regular intervals. Like a minute or two. For this I am using .net 4.6.1 with

1. System Timer, &
2. Task

Below is my code

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Download updates from server
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private void DownloadUpdate()
    {
        try
        {
            var package = string.Empty;
            if (_server != null)
            {
                timer.Stop();
                package = _server.Download();
                if (package.Length > 0)
                    _server.Install(package);
            }
        }

        finally
        {

            timer.Start();

        }

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// To carry out download asynchronous way
    /// </summary>
    private async void DowloadUpdateAsync()
    {
       await Task.Run(()=>DownloadUpdate());
    }
```

Just wanted to know, If its a correct approach to manage the intervals.

Comment: I don't know your full scenario, but I'm wondering why do you need this to be async. If `DownloadUpdate` is meant to run asynchronously, I think it shouldn't deal with timer (like stopping/starting it), even if you were running one task per time. I think you want to asynchonously download many packages in regular intervals, right?!

Comment: This might be more suited to the code review site. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Alisson - it has to check update on regular intervals, while downloading, timer needs to keep off and it will download only one package at a time.

Answer (score 0):

1. For `async` method, return `Task` if you don't want it to return a result. see [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh524395(v=vs.110).aspx#BKMK_TaskTReturnType).
2. <del>`Task.Run(()=>DownloadUpdate());` can be simplified as `Task.Run(DownloadUpdate);`</del>
3. I really don't see any reason why you need to wrap the task in an `async` method. Since `DownloadUpdate` is not asynchronous, it will block a thread anyway, all you need to do is run it as a `Task` or queue it to threadpool directly.

Comment: Task.Run(()=>Method()) is not equal to Task.Run(Method) here, since Run could not identify if the calling method is Func<Task> or Action. A typecast to Action is necessary.

Answer (score -1):

Adding on to Lifu's answer:

I would suggest that, you should start the timer in ContinueWith().

TPL uses the garbage collector's finalization mechanism to discover when a failed task has been abandoned resulting in the exception being **unobserved**. When that happens, the TaskScheduler class raises its UnobservedTaskException event. It is better to handle your exceptions. This is plus when using ContinueWith.

Try something like this:

```
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    public Program()
    {
        timer.Interval = 5000;
        timer.Elapsed += DownloadUpdate;
        timer.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void DownloadUpdate(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew((Action)DownloadUpdate).ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            bool shouldTimerStartAgain = true;
            if (t.IsFaulted)
            {
                // handle t.Exception
                // Compute if this task need to stop?
                // If so set shouldTimerStartAgain = false
            }
            if (shouldTimerStartAgain)
            {
                timer.Start();
            }
        });
    }

    private void DownloadUpdate()
    {
        var package = string.Empty;
        if (_server != null)
        {
            timer.Stop();
            package = _server.Download();
            if (package.Length > 0)
                _server.Install(package);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you want to handle the exceptions then use a `try/catch`.  You shouldn't be using `StartNew` like this, nor should you be using `ContinueWith` instead of an `async` method for something like this.

Comment: @Servy would you elaborate?